# Why ProtocolBuffers generate descriptor ?

Tags: protocol-buffers, descriptor

protocol buffers generate code to decode and encode message.

why it also generate descriptor code; the code seems to has no usage in encoding and decoding message process.

Has the descriptor any other usage?

Comment: this should be asked on a forum other than stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for an implementation detail of a spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are useful for debugging problems: fields and their values can be printed e.g. missing required fields could be printed automatically if parsing data fails because of it.

And descriptors will not be generated if you set following option in your .proto file.

```
option optimize_for = LITE_RUNTIME;
```